# Why doesn't my code enter a loop?

Tags: python, loops

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False  


flag = True
while flag != False:
    numInput = raw_input("Enter your first number: ")
    if is_number(numInput):
        numInput = float(numInput)
        flag = True
        break
    else:
        print "Error, only numbers are allowed"
```

I do not see the problem.
Why doesn't it enter a loop? 
Doesn't print anything, just gets stuck.

Comment: `flag != False` is the same as `flag`.

Comment: Likewise, `is_number(numInput) == True` should just be `is_number(numInput)`.

Comment: You might want to tell us what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Its the first part of a calculator.

Comment: if you don't see the "Enter your first number" the first time, then something might be wrong with your indentation. try printing something before the while loop to see where it gets stuck or simply if you just can't see anything on your standard output (which is where raw_input should've printed your "Enter your first..." text"

Comment: Its supposed to get a float.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. Its before this code even starts to run. oops. However you guys found many problems with my code so thanks for that :)

Comment: Your code works fine, as you've removed the `flag = False` line from the `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flag = False` is not required here:

```
else:
    print "Error, only numbers are allowed"
    flag = False  <--- remove this
```

Simply use:

```
while True:
    numInput = raw_input("Enter your first number: ")
    if is_number(numInput):
        numInput = float(numInput)
        break
    else:
        print "Error, only numbers are allowed"
```

demo:

```
Enter your first number: foo
Error, only numbers are allowed
Enter your first number: bar
Error, only numbers are allowed
Enter your first number: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while True:
    numInput = raw_input("Enter your first number: ")    
    try:
        numInput = float(numInput)
        break
    except:
        print "Error, only numbers are allowed"
```

Comment: also after the loop ends, the value will be assigned to the `numInput` variable so that you can use it the script..